# How to command substitution map in fish shell

Tags: fish

I would like to be able to do this:

```
bat misc | rg -v -e 'TXT|txt' | map path_explode
```

where

```sh
function map
   while read line       
      command $argv $line 
   end
end
```

and

```sh
function path_explode --description 'Return filename, ext, and directory from the path'
    echo $argv[1] | sed 's/\(.*\)\/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)$/\2\n\3\n\1/'
end
```

does that make sense? I get this error:

```
fish: Unknown command: path_explode
fish: 
command $argv $line 
        ^
in function 'map' with arguments 'path_explode'
```

Answer (score 0):

In fish 3 or later, variables can be used directly as commands, so you don't need `eval` or `command` in your `map` function.

Answer (score -1):

ohh I just need to use `eval` instead of command

cool :)